# How do i strip rows inside a Column-Table, based on the "outer" tables value in Power Query?

Tags: powerquery

Beeing pretty new to Power Query, I find myself faced with this problem I wish to solve.
I have a TableA with these columns. Example:

```
Key | Sprint | Index
-------------------------
A   | PI1-I1 | 1
A   | PI1-I2 | 2
B   | PI1-I3 | 1
C   | PI1-I1 | 1
```

I want to end up with a set looking like this:

```
Key | Sprint | Index | HasSpillOver
-------------------------
A   | PI1-I1 | 1     | Yes
A   | PI2-I2 | 2     | No
B   | PI1-I3 | 1     | No
C   | PI1-I1 | 1     | No
```

I thought I could maybe nestedjoin TableA on itself and then compare indicies and strip them away and then count rows in the table, like outlined below.

TableA=Key, Sprint, Index
// TableA Nested joined on itself (Key, Sprint, Index, Nested)

TableB=NestedJoin(#"TableA", "Key", #"TableA", "Key", "Nested", JoinKind.Inner)

TableC= Table.TransformColumns(#"TableB", {"Nested", (x)=>Table.SelectRows(x, each [Index] <x[Index])} )

.. and then do the count, however this throws an error:
Can not apply operator < on types List and Number.

Any suggestions how to approach this problem? Possibly (probably) in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define very well what "spillover" means but this should get you most of the way

Mine assumes adding another index. You could use what you have if it is relevant

Then the code counts the number of rows where the (2nd) index is higher, and the [Key] field matches. You could add code so that the Sprint field matches as well if relevant

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index.1", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index" ,"Count",(i)=>Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index" , each [Key]=i[Key] and [Index.1]>i[Index.1])))
in #"Added Custom"
```